# Change IP to domain name on linux

Tags: linux, ip, domain-name

All,

How is that we can convert an IP to a domain name address on linux machine.

Suppose i always access my Pc with http://127.0.0.1 from the browser

I want to change this to my.com

Thanks....

Comment: This belongs on superuser. But take a look at `man hosts`

Answer (score 7):

you can add a line like

```
127.0.0.1 my.host whatever.com
```

to /etc/hosts if you want to bind a hostname to an IP. In most default configurations this file is consulted first.

Answer (score 1):

I'n not sure exactly what you're asking, but if you just want to know how to look up a domain name associated with an IP address, you can use `dig -x` to do a [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup):

```
$ dig +short -x 69.59.196.211
stackoverflow.com.
```

Note that this won't always work, because there may be multiple domain names pointing at a single IP address, and it's not always the case that every IP address has a reverse DNS mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You should already be able to access that via http://localhost/, which is the standard name for 'this machine'.